# row_number 1 - row_number 2 sql

Tags: sql, database

I want to use sql query to add a new field with name Result with the same values in the below Table

[image]

for ex :
set the first value for Result field = vule2 field when row_id = 1  after that when row_id = 2 the Result field =  the first value for vule2 miunse value1 for row_id =1 (12672 - 3 ) = 12669 ....etc

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (value2 -
        sum(value1) over (order by row_id)
       ) + value1
from t;
```